# How to update Firebase pods during app initialization

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I am using firebase to create an iOS app in Xcode, but every once in a while I have to run pod update from terminal. I was wondering if there was a way to do this inside a swift file during the initialization of the app. P.S. I am a beginner to swift and firebase so detailed answers are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

Just run `pod update` from your `Podfile` and you should be golden.

Comment: But with that being said, don't hesitate to research the latest and greatest versions of the Firebase SDK and also integrate those pod versions into your Podfile.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your folder project, you can create a **.sh** file, and you can write the command: **pod update**

and you can run it with the command: **./nameFile.sh**
also you can write what you want to do in the file, for instance:

I want to update my Podfile, then copy the index.html and do a deploy.

> pod update
>
> cp index.html public/
>
> firebase deploy